# Lagging video feed using OpenCV with dual cameras

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to receive camera feed from 2 phones using OpenCV (both using WiFi). But one of the feed always "lags". When using a single camera feed, it works well. I tried receiving one using WiFi and the other using USB but the lag in 1 camera still persists (which is gone if I use that alone). How can I fix that? Or is this a limitation of my Hardware? I'm using this code (It's a Ball Tracking task):

```
def detect_objects(frame  , title):
    frame = imutils.resize(frame , width = 600)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame , (11 , 11) , 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred , cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv , GREEN_LOWER, GREEN_UPPER)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask , None , iterations = 2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask , None , iterations = 2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
   
    center = None
    height , width , _ = frame.shape
    mid_x  = width // 2 
    
    line_color = (0, 0, 255)  # BGR color (green in this case)
    line_thickness = 2
    direction = None
    cv2.line(frame , (mid_x , 0) , (mid_x , height) , line_color , line_thickness)

    if len(cnts) > 0:
        c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
        ((x , y) , radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
        if radius > MIN_RADIUS:
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),(0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)          
            add_text_detected(frame , title)
            return center

    if direction == None:
        add_text_lost(frame , title)
  

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ip_address_x = '####'
    ip_address_y = '####'
    port = 8080
    username = '####'
    password = '####'
    url_x = f'http://{username}:{password}@{ip_address_x}:{port}/video'
    url_y = f'http://{username}:{password}@{ip_address_y}:{port}/video'

    print("Video feed towards x axis from: ", url_x)
    print("Video feed towards y axis from: ", url_y)


    credentials = f'{username}:{password}'
    base64_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    auth_header = f'Basic {base64_credentials}'
    headers = {'Authorization': auth_header}

    cap_x = cv2.VideoCapture(url_x)
    cap_y = cv2.VideoCapture(url_y)
    DISPLAY_TEXT = ["Ball Lost" , "Ball Detected"]
    MIN_RADIUS = 10
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    font_scale = 1
    font_color = (255, 0 , 0)  
    font_thickness = 3
 
    FRAME_TITLE = 'Camera View'
    GREEN_LOWER = (29, 86, 6)
    GREEN_UPPER = (64, 255, 255)
    


    while(True):
        ret_x , frame_x = cap_x.read()
        ret_y , frame_y = cap_y.read()

        if not (ret_x):# and ret_y)  :
            print("No video feed!")
            break
    
        center_x = detect_objects(frame_x , 'View_X')
        center_y = detect_objects(frame_y , 'View_Y')

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what's going on. For anyone else who faces the same error in the future. I firstly guessed adding `multiprocessing` would make it work  but I coudn't multiprocess the part

```
cap_x = cv2.VideoCapture(url_x)
cap_y = cv2.VideoCapture(url_y)
```

Later I "concatenated" side by side the input frames from `cap_x` and `cap_y` (i.e. before the `detect_objects()` processing and observed the feed. Here itself I spotted that one of them lags. I figured this cold be due to different frame rate (FPS) coming into the 2 streams but this wasn't true (I set both on IP Webcam app to a low, 10 FPS value but that didn't work too). So finally this is likely due to one of these:

1. Different rates of data transfer in the 2 networks (less likely)
2. The openCV processing: In the code block above, one frame of y is "achieved" after 1 frame of x is processed. Now I'm not sure if a buffer is created internally/ it works in real time. But the problem is surely in one of these 2.

- The solution could be something around synchronisation of the 2 feeds. For example setting exact timestamps (obviously many times per second to make it practically useful) at which photos are clicked and then sent to the PC "fast enough" (as we need to make decisions based on that) for processing.